# RoR 3.1: Testing correct titles with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "LayoutLinks" do
  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
   get '/'
   response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
 end
end
```

Spec source: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb
(I'm reading the book)

I tried putting integrate_views and render_views, but it returned an undefined variable error.

```
$ guard
Guard is now watching at '[project dir]'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
F

Failures:

  1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
       expected css "title" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 13.15 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:3 # LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
```

Part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

For setting up everything I followed:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=asciicast

Part of my root directory: Has the title tag and inside "Name of Site | Home"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.should have_xpath("//title", :text => "Name of Site | Home")
```